# Ehcache concurrent read and write from multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, ehcache

I am having an issue with access to Ehcache when Thread1 puts a new key/value into the cache and the Thread2 tries to read it. Read by Thread2 doesn't return the value inserted by Thread1.

Note that first method is invoked by starting the application and the second one is invoked almost at the same time by a REST controller. Also in the example below I am using BlockingCache but it was also tested with a simple cache. Explicit locking was also tested.

It looks like so:

```
private void processThread1(Object object) {
    BlockingCache blockingCache = new BlockingCache(getCache());
    blockingCache.put(new Element(object.getKey(), object));
}

private void processThread2(Object object) {
    BlockingCache blockingCache = new BlockingCache(getCache());
    // this value is not updated by processThread1(..) when
    // it's accessed, although processThread1(..) method call 
    // finishes before this method is called
    SomeObject someObject = blockingCache.get(object.getKey());
}

Cache getCache() {
    return cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
}
```